# How to listen to a value stored in Secure Storage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

Basically what I would like to achieve is kind of creating a Stream on a value saved in the Secure Storage. Currently I am storing the jsonwebtoken in the Secure Storage and I would like to logout the user or login (Show different screens) whenever the token is given or removed from the storage (The value changes from null to a String or String to null.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think what you need is ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder, but I have the question why?  I don't understand the pattern / why this approach.  What's removing the token if not your code (that could then log the user in/out)?

Comment: Well the code removes the value, but the homescreen that is called in main should change based on the given value

Comment: Gotcha.  Maybe this will help (state management video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I

Comment: @socasanta I guess that means I should wrap the main widget with a Listener. But how exactly do I set it to listen on that value in secure storage? Does anyone of you have an example code on how to do that? Based on that value then, the home widget should change as I said before.

Comment: I don't see how that's doable.  Instead, whatever changes the value in secure storage would need to change the value of an object that you are tracking the state of.